# Prove that $f=x^6+ax+5$ is reducible over $\mathbb{Z_7},\forall a\in\mathbb{Z_7}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials

We have $f=x^6+ax+5\in\mathbb{Z_7}$ and we have to show that it is reducible on $\mathbb{Z_7}$, $\forall a\in\mathbb{Z_7}$. Here are all my steps:

---

For $a=0$ we'll get $f=x^6+5\in\mathbb{Z_7}$. But $\forall x\in\mathbb{Z_7}$ with $x\neq0\Rightarrow x^6=1$. Therefore $f\neq0$ and it means that $f$ doesn't have linear factors. How  can  we continue from here?

For $a\neq0$ and $x\neq0$ we'll get $f=ax+6$, $\forall x\in\mathbb{Z_7}$. Here the only solution for which $f$ is reducible over $\mathbb{Z_7}$ is for $x=a^{-1}$. But if $x\neq a^{-1}$ then $ f$ is not reducible over $\mathbb{Z_7}$.

---

> How can I show that $f$ is reducible over $\mathbb{Z_7},\forall a\in\mathbb{Z_7}$ ? Where am I wrong?

Comment: when $a\neq 0$, $a^{-1}$ is a root of $f$, so $x-a^{-1}$ is a linear factor of $f$.

Comment: @EwanDelanoy we are not interested when $x\neq a^{-1}$ ?

Comment: @Lucas: the $a=0$ case appears to not have an obvious *linear* factor, but this does not prevent the polynomial from being reducible over $\Bbb Z_7$.

Comment: @abiessu can you show your method?

Comment: @Lucas $f$ is reducible or it is not. You cannot say, "f is reducible for this value and f is not reducible for this other value."

Comment: I'll defer to the answer by Linus S.; basically, since $5\equiv -9\equiv -100\pmod 7$, we have $x^6+5\equiv x^6-9\equiv x^6-100\pmod 7$, and both of these polynomials can be factored as a difference of squares...

Answer (score 3):

As you said, if $a \neq 0$ we have $f(a^{-1})=0$ which means that $f$ has a root and thus is reducible [$x-a^{-1}$ is a factor].

If $a=0$ you need to factor $x^6+5$. To do this note that $5 \equiv -100 \pmod{7}$.

Comment: Interestingly, $5=-10^2\pmod 7$ implies $5=-3^2\pmod 7$.

Comment: @LinusS. have an ideea how we can figure out that $5 \equiv -100 \pmod{7}$ implies $5 \equiv -9 \pmod{7}$ ? is a trick or a simple calculation ?

Comment: It's sort of a trick. $10^2 = (7+3)^2 \equiv 3^2 \pmod 7$, because if you expand out $(7+3)^2$ with binomial expansion each term will have $\cdot 7$ in it except for the last term. In general, $(ka+b)^n \pmod a \equiv b^n \pmod a$

Comment: @LinusS. I missed the easier one :)

Answer (score 2):

Note that $f(a^{-1})=0$ as you noted before when $a$ is not $0$. Then we know that $(x-a^{-1})$ is a factor. We can do a "complete the sextic" approach on the function as follows:

$f(x) = (x-a^{-1})(x^5) = x^6-a^{-1}x^5$

$f(x) = (x-a^{-1})(x^5+a^{-1}x^4) = x^6 + a^{-2}x^4$

Verify that $f(x) = (x-a^{-1})(x^5+a^{-1}x^4+a^{-2}x^3+a^{-3}x^2 + a^{-4}x + 2a) = x^6-a^{-5}x + 2ax - 2= x^6-ax + 2ax +5 = x^6+ax+5$

The last $2a$ came from the observation that $a^{-1}$ was a root of both $x^6-ax$ and $x^6+ax+5$, meaning that the two functions were some multiple of $(x-a^{-1})$ from each other.

Also, when $a=0$, we need to factorize $f(x) = x^6+5 = x^6-9 = (x^3+3)(x^3-3)$.

Comment: Linus I don't understand the begining part, can you explain again what is your purpose?

Comment: If $f(a^{-1})=0$, then $f(x) = (x-a^{-1}) \cdot g(x)$ for some polynomial $g(x)$. Then, I basically try to find $g(x)$ to make the proof more complete, but this isn't **actually** necessary (though it's probably better to follow through).

Comment: I suppose that you divide $f(x)$ at $x-a^{-1}$ to obtain $g(x)$, isn't it?

Comment: Pretty much, yeah. Except I guess-and-checked more than actually divide (but it's the same concept)

Answer (score 1):

You have solved the $a\neq 0$ case with the exception of saying that $x=a^{-1}$ is the solution and no more need be said about this case; taking only the $a=0$ case, we immediately have $f(x)=x^6+5\equiv 6\pmod 7$ for all $x$, and therefore there are no linear factors in this case.  However, we do have that $5=14-9=-9+2\cdot 7\equiv -9 \pmod 7$.  This brings us to

$$f(x)=x^6+5\equiv x^6-9\pmod 7$$

$x^6-9$ is a difference of squares as $(x^3)^2$ and $3^2$, leading to the factorization $x^6-9=(x^3+3)(x^3-3)$.  The fact that there are no linear factors suggests that $3,-3$ are both cubic non-residues modulo $7$, and it is easy to verify that the only cubic residues modulo $7$ are $\{-1,1\}$.

Comment: abiessu why is wrong if we say that $x=a^{-1}$ is the solution? because it means that $x-a^{-1}$ is a root for a liniar factorization

Comment: What we say is that $x=a^{-1}$ is the solution; this also means that $x-a^{-1}$ is a linear factor of the given polynomial.  Saying that $x\neq a^{-1}$ does not produce a solution is not particularly productive after that since what we want to prove is that the function is reducible, and we have done that for all invertible $a$.

Comment: what you want to mean by "not particularly productive..." ?

Comment: I mean to say that "we have already proven that $f(x)$ is reducible for $a\neq 0$ and a solution is $x=a^{-1}$ and thus saying that $f(x)$ is not reducible for $x\neq a^{-1}$ does not help to prove that $f(x)$ is reducible."

Comment: can you help here http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1301127/how-we-can-find-a-gamma-f