# How we can find $A_{(\Gamma_f)}$?

Tags: calculus, integration

We have $f,g:[-4,4]\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$, $f(x)=x^2+2$ and $g(x)=x+4$. We need to find the crowd area between the graphs f and g.

I know that $A_{(\Gamma_f)}=\int_a^b|f(x)|dx$ but in this case how we can find $A_{(\Gamma_f)}$ ? I think we need to find **x (commune abscissa)** and it involving that:

$f(x)=g(x)\Rightarrow x=\{-1,2\}$

> How can I continue from here ?

Comment: Note that in this case we have $|f(x)|=|x^2+2|=x^2+2$, so you need to evaluate $$\int_{-1}^2(x^2+2)\text dx$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In our case $A_{(\Gamma_f)}=\int_a^b|f(x)-g(x)|dx$ and as I said $f(x)=g(x)\Rightarrow x=\{-1,2\}$

Therefore $A_{(\Gamma_f)}=\int_a^b|f(x)-g(x)|dx=\int_{-1}^2|f(x)-g(x)|dx=\int_{-1}^2 [g(x)-f(x)] dx=\frac{9}{2}$

Comment: Ah, you have a different definition of $A_{\Gamma_f}$ here than in your question...